# eclipse import local git repository, two set of same file shown in package explorer

Tags: git, eclipse, import

In eclipse, I right click my local repository in git repositories view and choose import, after import, I go to package explorer, I see two set of same file shown, as the following image shown (e.g. cfms-db-update folder shown under CFMS in upper and shown in lower also, but lower has grey word [CFMS_staging_kei20201211]).

1. why will this happen?
2. If I want to change code of a file, as the file shown in both upper part and lower part, where should I change (upper or lower one)?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You have imported the root directory and its subfolders as projects (probably because they contain a `pom.xml` file and therefore have been detected as a project) and in the *Project Explorer* all projects are shown flat, on the first level one under the other, even if they are nested. In other words, each subfolder is shown twice, as a subfolder of the first project and as a project of its own.
2. The same files and folders are shown twice, so it doesn't matter which ones you choose to open and to edit.

Answer (score 1):

1. It is possible the CMS folder reference multiples submodules (nested Git repositories). Check that by looking for a `.gitmodules` file under `CMS`.
   Or:

- CMS is a multi-module maven project (and you see all its submodule in the left-corner upper part)
- each maven module are imported in the Package Explorer and are shown in the bottom part, but are still part of the same CMS Git repository.

2. Both parts reference the same Git repository so you can change in either.

Comment: I don't think it has to do with Git submodules (wouldn't the projects in that case have different labels for different Git repositories?), but that the subfolders were imported as separate Maven projects because they contain a `pom.xml` file.

Comment: @howlger Yes, that is what the multi-modules part of my answer addresses.

Comment: The root directory does not contain a parent POM. If there is no parent POM (somewhere else), there are just multiple independent Maven projects, not multiple Maven modules.